# can not install software in linux error as dpkg was interrupted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono

I was trying to install mono using following commands,

1. `sudo apt-get install mono-*`

unfortunately, I closed the terminal while it installing. again i started to reinstall but shown error like

> Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable)

I tried below commands for solution,

1. `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`
2. `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

But now I am getting the error like

> dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
>   to correct the problem.

how do I fix this one?

Comment: you fix it by doing what it says.  run that command and it clears things out.  then you can reinstall mono

Comment: @RussellUhl now showing like "dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001' near line 0:
 newline in field name `#padding'
"

Answer (score 30):

This error occurs when you stop any installation while it's in progress. Regardless of whether you are using the terminal or the Ubuntu app center, the error will still be generated.

You can solve this by removing the broken installation. To do so, enter the following commands in the terminal in the order they are written.

```sh
   cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
   sudo rm *
   sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Just saved me a ton of work - thank you so much! Wish I could set this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: i am getting this  "dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001' near line 0: newline in field name `#padding' " when use this command.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot I got a satisfactory result:

I found some places saying to run commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But none of those above worked.

The solution that worked to me:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

next time please don't use

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

or anything like that.
Decent way to do this is

```
sudo killall apt-get
```

Comment: ok i do.now i am getting  "dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001' near line 0: newline in field name `#padding' " error what i do?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to update your ubuntu by command :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Sometime the dpkg needs some update to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Remove the lock:**

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

**2. Move to the updates dir:**

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
```

**3. Remove the all files from updates dir**

```
sudo rm *
```

**4. Take a fresh update**

```
sudo apt-get update
```